# Why this MongoDB installation step occur an error?

Tags: database, mongodb, ubuntu, installation, apt

```
wget -qO - https://www.mongodb.org/static/pgp/server-5.0.asc | sudo apt-key add -
```

When I run the above command to import the MongoDB public GPG Key I got this error.
The MongoDB documentation has like these steps to install. How do I install MongoDB's latest version through PPA?

```
Warning: apt-key is deprecated. Manage keyring files in trusted.gpg.d instead (see apt-key(8)).
gpg: invalid key resource URL '/tmp/apt-key- 
gpghome.y7PLc7iFDy/home:manuelschneid3r.asc.gpg'
gpg: keyblock resource '(null)': General error
gpg: key 7721F63BD38B4796: 2 signatures not checked due to missing keys
gpg: key 8C718D3B5072E1F5: 75 signatures not checked due to missing keys
gpg: key 7721F63BD38B4796: 2 signatures not checked due to missing keys
gpg: key 1488EB46E192A257: 1 signature not checked due to a missing key
gpg: key 1488EB46E192A257: 1 signature not checked due to a missing key
gpg: key D94AA3F0EFE21092: 3 signatures not checked due to missing keys
gpg: key 871920D1991BC93C: 1 signature not checked due to a missing key
gpg: Total number processed: 17
gpg:       skipped new keys: 17
```

Answer (score 1):

Could you please try the following? Two people had similar issue as yours when installing MongoDB and they solved removing the gpg key.

```
sudo rm /etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d/home:manuelschneid3r.gpg
```

[source: askubuntu.com](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1246031/gpg-invalid-key-resource-url-following-docker-official-guide)

Comment: sudo rm "/etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d/home:manuelschneid3r.asc"

Worked this